# Can the design of the "inform moderator" flag count be updated to a higher contrast design for readability?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm seeing this on the report to moderator box:

[image: The number of inform moderator flags remaining is too dark to read]

Can the design of the "inform moderator" flag count be updated to a higher contrast design for readability? The black text on a dark red background is not very readable.

*Chrome 25 (dev) on Mac OS X 10.8*

Comment: Thanks for raising this - I've pinged the developer on the old thread. Would you propose something specific to fix is - is it a contrast issue or a colorblind issue or a sizing issue in your estimation?

Comment: For me this is a contrast issue. If the text was white that would help immensely. AFAIK I'm not colorblind :)

Comment: black on red is indeed not usually very readable, at all.

Answer (score 1):

That old post was about an alignment issue, not a color issue. Your screenshot clearly shows that it was indeed fixed.

That doesn't make *your* issue any less valid though, so this will be fixed as well after the next build (It turns out that red wasn't the intended background color here).

Comment: Re-read the old post. You are absolutely right. Fixed the question accordingly.